# How to write an interactive function which repeats when the last key in the keybinding is repeatedly pressed?

Tags: key-bindings, commands, interactive

I want to repeat a function when the last key in the key binding is repeatedly pressed.

For example, say the keybinding is `C-n` for `next-line`, what I want to happen is that `next-line` is repeated when I just press `n`. Also, I need some way to end the repetition. Ideally any other key press should do what it normally does.

I have no idea where to begin with this so no close attempts I could show.

Note: In the example above it's not actually important that `C-n` runs the function. The first execution of the function could be on the first separate `n` key press.